# Formal definition of sum over finite index set

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to define arbitrary sum over a finite set ? Given an abelian additive group $(G,+)$, and $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of elements in $G$, where $I$ is a finite index set.
What is the formal definition of this :
$$\sum_{i\in I} a_i$$
Thanks for answers :)

Comment: You can find this at ProofWiki: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Summation along with a proof that it is well-defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\phi: \{1,\ldots,n\} \to I$ is a bijection, then I would define the sum as:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{\phi(i)}$$

where a sum $\sum_{\ell =1}^t b_{\ell}$ in $G$ is defined using induction.

Comment: Thus, we start with a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and we define inductivly "ordered sum" through the sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $s_0 = a_0$ and $s_{n+1} = s_n + a_{n+1}$, and we denote $s_n$ by $\sum_{i=0}^n a_n$. Then for any family $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ ($I$ finite), we define for any bijection $\phi : [\![0,n]\!]\to I$ the arbitrary sum as $\sum_{i\in I} a_i = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{\phi(i)}$ ?

Comment: @Phoenix exactly.